# initSql property and DriverManagerDataSource

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, connection-pooling

I configured the following `DriverManagerDataSource` for my junits

```
<bean id="myDS"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${ds.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${ds.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${ds.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${ds.password}"/>
</bean>
```

Now I want to add the `initSql` property to make the DS execute an sql command at connection creation time. I tried the following configuration but it doesn't work.

```
<bean id="myDS"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${ds.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${ds.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${ds.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${ds.password}"/>
    <property name="connectionProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="initSql">select set_limit(0.1)</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

How to add the `initSql` property on a `DriverManagerDataSource` ?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work, do you get an exception or the query doesn't work?  Which database / driver are you using - does it support the initSql property

Comment: No error but the setting `initSql` isn't take into account (the junit result is not the one excpected). The db is Postgresql and the driver is one from http://jdbc.postgresql.org

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [DBCP basic datasource](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html), that supports specifying a set of sqls to be executed at the time of creation of connections.

The DriverManagerDatasource is not recommended to be used for deployment as it doesn't do any connection pooling. It is better to use DBCP or CP30.

Comment: As I said I use `DriverManagerDataSource` in a test context

Comment: But DBCP will work for your purpose. See link: http://mike.hostetlerhome.com/2009/02/20/be-careful-with-drivermanagerdatasource/